# Protect IP webcam's RTSP port 554 with firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, webcam

I have a IP web camera and I'm opening the port to the internet through the WIFI router. It's useful that I can check the live streaming outdoors on phones or laptops. But there's one thing I'm concerning, even though I have a (strong) user/password on the device, any hackers could brute force the device with a bunch of random passwords and eventually he could get the access to the device and can see the streaming as well. It's not good feel somebody could see my life like that. So I want to secure the device with firewall or something. But I have no idea how and even it's possible or not. It's not Linux (probably) so I cannot port forward or hopefully SSH-ing to the camera and setting up iptables rules. So, can I protect my IP webcam from attackers?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, my recommendation would be closing your port forwarding and getting a router with a VPN server, then you just connect to the VPN from wherever you are and view it by it's local IP address. Word of advice, pick a IP scheme that you likely won't find in the wild, like a 172.29.156.0/24 (something in private space, but rarely seen)

Comment: “Secure it with a firewall” will not prevent brute force attacks if you forward a port to a device like your camera.  Your router is already a firewall by the way